# What type of Azure Alert Signal do I use for ILogger's LogWarning, LogInformation and LogDebug?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I've setup my web app to use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/tutorial-asp-net-core) and I'm receiving the data in the Azure portal. I've also set up [Application Insights Logging with .NET](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/ilogger.md#aspnet-core-applications) and I can now create alerts and have an action created for sending myself an email when specific conditions are triggered Ex. A new exception that I log with [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

```
_logger.LogError(new Exception(), "some message");
```

But now I want to create an alert with an email notification when I log warnings, debugs and information, and errors (w/ no exception).

Ex.

```
_logger.LogInformation("testing LogInformation");
_logger.LogWarning("testing LogWarning");
_logger.Debug("testing LogDebug");
_logger.Error("testing LogError w/ no exception");
```

**QUESTION** - When I create an alert, what signal do I use for log warnings, debug and information?

**FYI** - When I created the alert for exceptions I used this "exceptions" under metrics [image].

But I don't really see anything else in the list of all signals to use for the logging of warnings, information, etc.

**WHAT I TIRED** - I tried creating a alert w/ the signal name of "All Administrative Operations" and then setting the level to warning, but that didn't do anything when I created a log warning server side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific signal type for this kind of logging. It ends up as an entry in the `traces` table in Application Insights. However, there is the `Custom log search` that you can use. It allows you to define a kusto query and create an alert:

[image]

The [severitylevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.severitylevel?view=azure-dotnet#fields) indicates whether it is logged as a warning etc.

An example condition is to create an alert whenever the number of rows returned in the given period is greater dan 0:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks Peter. Do you have advice on using this type of alert rule to notify an admin vs sending out a simple email using sendgrid? I'm trying to weight the pros and cons of both to see if one has any advantage over the other when I get into production mode.

Comment: @user1186050 *sending out a simple email using sendgrid* you mean doing that in code directly?

Comment: ya. I have a service that I created that sends emails. Ex. _service.SendEmail(from, to, body)

Comment: @user1186050 For me the reason to use an alert vs sending an email using code is the fact that I am flexible regarding the criteria that have to be met before sending an alert and the fact that I can change the way the alerts are delivered withouth having to modify the code. Say you want to exclude some specific exception, then you can just alter the kusto query instead of having to modify your code and redeploy your app. Or you want to add sms alerting to the mix, or put a notification in a Microsoft Teams channel or Slack channel or whatsoever.