# How to send a mail when both handled and not handled execption occur

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a App Service which is a Web App implemented as a MVC application running in azure. I want to send a mail when an exception occur. The execption could be both those that are handled in try ...catch. and those that are not handled in code. I hope to set this up in azure without changing in MVC code. Can somebody guide me in the right direction if this is possible or not.

//Tony Johansson

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can e[nable Application Insights auto-instrumentation monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps-net#enable-auto-instrumentation-monitoring) if your environment [is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview#supported-environments-languages-and-resource-providers). This will log unhandled exceptions.

As far as handled exceptions is concerned, you will need to modify your code for those to be logged, either using something like `ILogger.LogError(ex)` or using the Application Insights SDK directly using `TelemetryClient.TrackException(ex)`.

For more details about [logging in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line) and [log destinations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging-providers) see the respective links.

Once Application Insights is integrated you can create alerts when an exception occurs and send an email. Details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75830883/932728)

Start with creating an alert based on the "Custom log search" signal:

[image]

Then specify that the alert must be send when any exception occurs:

[image]

Finally, specify what action should be taken, like send an email.

Note: there are also metrics signals available that you can use to alert when an exception occurs:

[image]

Thing is, this will only show how many did occur in the timeframe but does not show any details regarding the actual exceptions. That is why I prefer the "Custom log search" signal because then you are able to create a query that actually retrieves the exception details.

Comment: To log the info is not so important but what is importwnt is to be able to send an email as soon as an exception occur with the same information that could be logged.

Comment: @tony once application insights is integrated you can set up alerts to send an email when an exception occurs.,

Comment: Is it possible to send the Email at the same time as the Exception occur. Now it seems as the mail is being send much later. So I mean if I for example select the about in the navigation meny and this cause an exception is should be sent at once. If I then select another meny item and this also cause an exeption a second mail should be send.